# Performance loss with int and long overloads

Tags: c#, .net, performance, entity-framework, entity

**Question:**

Why does passing a list from a protected internal class to an API method and then back to my UI take 4 seconds when direct data access in Entity takes .4? Is it due to the actual passing of the list through these methods?

**Background:**

I wish to create an "API" layer that sits between my data access layer using Entity Framework and my UI layer. The idea is to limit access to the CRUD operations and force everything through the API however I'm noticing terrible performance.

When I use my class structure here, the get method in this case takes **4 seconds** to run:

```
public class API
{
    DataAccessClass _dataAccess = new DataAccessClass();

    public List<Items> GetById(int id)
    {
        return _dataAccess.Get(id);
    }

    protected internal class DataAccessClass
    {
        protected internal List<Items> GET(int id)
        { 
            using (var context = dbcontext)
            {
                return context.GetItems();
            }
        }
        protected internal List<Items> GET(long id)
        { 
            using (var context = dbcontext)
            {
                return context.GetItems();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However when I use my dbcontext directly in code (which I want to prevent), it runs in **.4 seconds** using the same code found in the protected class above:

```
using (var context = dbcontext)
{
     return context.GetItems();
}
```

**EDIT:**

When I exclude the data access portion of the API which is the protected internal portion, and run the using statement in the API directly (just cutting out the protected internal portion) then I get the acceptable .4 seconds.

Comment: This is going to be difficult to answer unless we can reproduce what your seeing. How large is the list your passing? In general though the list is being passed by reference mostly so it shouldn't matter. What does your data access class look like?

Comment: The data access class is listed above... it's the protected internal part. Other than that is uses entity directly using entitycontext.object.tolist(); The data set is small. 4-6 records on average. The only thing being done differently is I can use the "data access" code directly in the UI and the issues go away.

Comment: oh ok, didn't see that class, that's quite bizarre, a `protected internal class`. What exactly is `GetItem()`? Obviously, nothing should take 4 seconds with 4-6 records. But right now I can't repro what your seeing.

Comment: I updated my main post with more details under "edit". Maybe that helps. The get item is the equivalent of: EntityContext.ObjectName.ToList(); I left the details of that out since the code runs fine outside of the protected internal class so I don't think it's relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To solve my performance issue, I removed overloads from the GET class above.**

My performance issues from the original question where resolved by changing method names on two of my get methods (one that took an int and one long). Not sure why these overloads causes issues but by removing the overloads and specifying names directly, my issue with performance was resolved.

**My working class looks like:**

```
public class API
{
    DataAccessClass _dataAccess = new DataAccessClass();

    public List<Items> GetById(int id)
    {
        return _dataAccess.Get(id);
    }

    protected internal class DataAccessClass
    {
        protected internal List<Items> GetByInt(int id)
        { 
            using (var context = dbcontext)
            {
                return context.GetItems();
            }
        }
        protected internal List<Items> GetByLong(long id)
        { 
            using (var context = dbcontext)
            {
                return context.GetItems();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do your methods ``GetByInt()`` and``GetByLong()`` (as well as the previous overloads) have an ``id`` parameter? They are not using it. And if they were using it, C# applies automatic conversion between number types in many places. Perhaps your performance issue has anything to do with that?

Comment: In production I do use the id just not for the provided example. I'm assuming at this point it has to do with that because as soon as I remove the "guess work" from the compiler, it works fine.